# Remove the header for "winnower"

Tags: header-footer

I am using the "winnower" document template for my assignment from Overleaf.

And I want to remove the header written "The Winnower" for every page.

I wonder how I should erase that.
I attached the snapshot of it.
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the community with a link to the "winnower" Overleaf template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick way is to add the line

```
\lhead[]{}
```

to the preamble. This will override the setting

```
\lhead[The Winnower]{The Winnower}
```

in the class file. Also, if you don't like the top rule, you can add the following line as suggested by @GonzaloMedina in a comment

```
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
```

The template and `.cls` file can be found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/3065511fjccmn#/8488621/).

[image]

A sample code from there:

```
\documentclass{winnower}    
\begin{document}    
\title{Title}

\author{Firstname1 Lastname1}
\affil{Department1, Institution1, City1, State1 Zip1, Country1}
\author{Firstname2 Lastname2}
\affil{Department1, Institution1, City2, State2 Zip2, Country2}

\lhead[]{}    
\date{}    
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse accumsan magna est, quis elementum leo laoreet eu. Donec sollicitudin elit non massa venenatis, in viverra dolor sagittis. Maecenas ac justo pulvinar, consectetur mauris hendrerit, vulputate lacus. Etiam tristique sapien quis sem commodo, et eleifend tortor viverra. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus vel tempus risus, sit amet consectetur massa. Duis rutrum lectus eu ligula egestas iaculis. Sed condimentum, ipsum in dignissim condimentum, nisi turpis blandit massa, et aliquam magna ligula eget lacus. Donec ac eleifend nulla, quis cursus nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse accumsan magna est, quis elementum leo laoreet eu. Donec sollicitudin elit non massa venenatis, in viverra dolor sagittis. Maecenas ac justo pulvinar, consectetur mauris hendrerit, vulputate lacus. Etiam tristique sapien quis sem commodo, et eleifend tortor viverra. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus vel tempus risus, sit amet consectetur massa. Duis rutrum lectus eu ligula egestas iaculis. Sed condimentum, ipsum in dignissim condimentum, nisi turpis blandit massa, et aliquam magna ligula eget lacus. Donec ac eleifend nulla, quis cursus nisi.
\end{abstract}    

%-------------------------------------------------%
\section{Section Heading}
%-------------------------------------------------%
.
.
. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Overleaf fives acces to the `.cls` file (and other files too): https://www.overleaf.com/3065548vggqyv#/8488744/

Comment: Perhaps you could also suggest `\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}` to kill the rule; if there is no header, the rule has no meaning.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina True, I added this suggestion.